# How do I see a certain member's permissions in discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, discord.js, replit

I tried this in different ways but I can't find the right one.

```
{name: `**Permissions:**`, value: `${user.permissions.cache.size}`,inline: false}
```

It says ".size is undefined"
I want to display something like this: [image: Here]

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `user` is a `GuildMember` instance, just use `.permissions`. There is no `cache` property. This has everything you need to handle a member's permissions

```js
member.permissions.toArray() // all permissions this member has as an array
member.permissions.has("PERMISSION_FLAG") // check if member has a certain permission
```

Comment: How do I shorten this: [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/924212256835780638/927050857575501904/unknown.png)

Comment: You can map it.